# How to execute a table of queries in order via Snowpark?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of DDL statements, the table has four columns but the important ones are the columns 'DDL' and 'Level'. I have a Snowpark python code in VSCode that will execute the DDL statements but I want the code to execute the statements in order of Level i.e. Level 5 statements will execute first, Level 4 next, all the way down to Level 0 statements executing last. E.g.

| DDL | Level |
| --- | --- |
| create or replace view db.schema.view | 0 |
| create or replace table db.schema2.table(col varchar, col2 int) | 1 |
| create or replace view db.schema3.view_phones | 0 |
| create or replace table db.schema4.table_jobs(col varchar, col2 varchar) | 2 |
| create or replace table db.schema.table_phones(col varchar) | 1 |
| create or replace table db.schema.table_words(col varchar, col2 int) | 2 |
| create or replace table db.schema.table_songs(col varchar, col2 int) | 3 |
| create or replace table db.schema.table_drinks(col varchar, col2 int) | 4 |
| create or replace table db.schema.table_dbs(col varchar, col2 int) | 5 |
| create or replace table db.schema.tables(col varchar, col2 int) | 5 |

My Snowpark python code:

```
tableName = 'DATABASE.SCHEMA.DDL_TABLE'
query_table = new_session.table(tableName)
df = query_table.to_pandas()

for int in df.index:
    command = df["DDL"][int] 
    async_job = new_session.sql(command).collect_nowait()
    print(async_job)
print('Done')
```

It's running as an async job which means each statement of the same level should execute together. The reason for this is that Level 0 objects are dependent on some of the other objects in Level 5, such as a Level 0 view needing a level 5-1 table to exist before it itself can be created. Not sure how to account for statements that encounter an error in creating which would mess up the views in lower levels being created so if anyone also has any idea on that end then it would also be appreciated but the main issue is adding some sort of order by level to the code so they are executed by level. Thanks in advance for anyone's help!

Comment: What type of indication are you expecting for a level of jobs to indicate to this code that all of the async jobs are complete before moving to the next level of jobs?

Comment: Also, depending on how many DDL statements you have, it'd probably be easier to just sort your df by level and then iterate through it in a synchronous fashion.  These statements will execute extremely fast, anyway.

Comment: @MikeWalton I'm not sure what indication I'm expecting to be honest as I haven't yet figured that out, but if they execute really fast as you say maybe I could have them wait 5-10 seconds between each level to ensure all levels are created before moving to the next? I just need to figure out how to get the process to check each object has created and to rerun the ddl if they error but I'm not there yet. Also yes, I'll try sorting it by level instead - is it just a case of replacing "DDL" by "level"? Or do I need an extra line? Sorry, I'm new to Snowpark/Python - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As Mike indicated probably sync execution will make more sense. The following script orders by level.

```py
# Create a SparkSession
from snowflake.snowpark import Session, functions as F, types as T
import os,json;configs = json.load(open(os.path.expanduser("~/credentials.json")))
session = Session.builder.configs(configs).getOrCreate()

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("DDL", T.StringType(), True),
    T.StructField("Level", T.IntegerType(), True)
])

# Create the data as a list of tuples
data = [
    ("create or replace view db.schema.view", 0),
    ("create or replace table db.schema2.table(col varchar, col2 int)", 1),
    ("create or replace view db.schema3.view_phones", 0),
    ("create or replace table db.schema4.table_jobs(col varchar, col2 varchar)", 2),
    ("create or replace table db.schema.table_phones(col varchar)", 1),
    ("create or replace table db.schema.table_words(col varchar, col2 int)", 2),
    ("create or replace table db.schema.table_songs(col varchar, col2 int)", 3),
    ("create or replace table db.schema.table_drinks(col varchar, col2 int)", 4),
    ("create or replace table db.schema.table_dbs(col varchar, col2 int)", 5),
    ("create or replace table db.schema.tables(col varchar, col2 int)", 5)
]

# Create the DataFrame
df = session.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema).group_by("LEVEL").agg(F.array_agg("DDL").alias("stmts")).sort(F.col("LEVEL").desc())
df.show()
print("Processing statements...")
for (level, stmts) in df.collect():
    print(f">>>> Processing statements at level {level}")
    for stmt in json.loads(stmts):
        try:
            session.sql(stmt)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error at level {level}")
```

Comment: Thanks @orellabac, the thing is the table could have like over 100 rows and having them execute asynchronously would be more efficient for the amount of queries there potentially could be. The table I'm working with now to test has over 180 rows. Could you also explain why sync would make more sense than async? Thanks!

Comment: If the snippets are simple, the might be quick and you will require less effort for trouble shooting. You can for each level do asyncjobs and capture the asyncjobs and then continue

Comment: Something like:
def wait_for_all_jobs_to_complete(async_job_list):
    while any(not job.is_done() for job in async_job_list):
        time.sleep(2)  # Sleep for 2 seconds (you can adjust this as needed)